# PHP-CLI Sudo Execution

Tags: sudo, php

I am running a cli-script, that requires a exec('sudo ...'); call. I know it is not safe on the web, but how can it be done in cli? The script is executed by a user known as "btcdbit", who is in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience setting the NOPASSWD option doesn't always work and even if it does it seems unsafe.  Seems to me that a better approach - if you're able to use it - would involve using phpseclib to do sudo through SSH.  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$sftp = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$sftp->login('username', 'password');

echo $sftp->read('username@username:~$');
$sftp->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $sftp->read('#Password:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#Password:#', $lines)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $sftp->read('username@username:~$');
}
?>
```

The website "[sudo in php](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sudo.htm)" elaborates

Answer (score 1):

So long as btcdbit is in sudoers for the program that you want it to be able to run, you should be able to use any of the PHP functions like `exec` or `system` to run it. Make sure that you use the NOPASSWD option in sudoers (see http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/18/linux-tips-password-usage-in-sudo-passwd-nopasswd/ for example) if you don't want it to get caught up asking btcdbit for a password.

Comment: what if btcdbit does not have a password

Comment: @macintosh264, I would try setting it up with the NOPASSWD option anyway. Can you clarify what you're experiencing when you attempt to run `exec` through the `php` program? Does it just get "stuck"?

Answer (score -2):

It should be just as simple as exec('/usr/bin/sudo {script}').